# Order proof using axiomatic

Tags: real-numbers

I started today studying real numbers axiomatic and I'm a bit stuck showing a proof of a property of order in real numbers.
This is the problem:

> if $r<0,$ then $-r>0$.

I have to do it just using axiomatic.
Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: if $r<0$, then $0=-r+r<-r$

Comment: you mean *axioms*?

Comment: Yes I do. Proving it by axioms

Comment: I see you say r+(-r)<-r, its "obvius" from r<0 and adding (-r) to both sides. But you are using a property and not axioms. Do you get my point?

Comment: What are the axioms you are using?  You should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3605260/edit) them into you question

Comment: I have available to use two axioms;

Comment: I)A number only can be >0, <0. If not then the number is 0.

Comment: Don't you have any axioms regarding the interaction between $<$, $+$, and $\times$?

Comment: If a>0 and b>0, then a+b>0 and ab>0. I don't have the interaction if a,b<0. But I can use all axioms of real numbers equality (conmutativity, asociativity etc)